# Как вывести имя переменной массива

Tags: c#, массивы

Имеется массив из переменных

```
double[] sort = new double[] { temp1, temp2, temp3, temp4, temp5, temp6}
```

Переменные уже имеют значение. Далее я произвожу сортировку.
Какой функцией можно вывести имя первой переменной в массиве после сортировки?

Comment: Никакой, после компиляции переменные могут иметь другие имена или вообще отсутствовать. Заведите класс со свойствами "Имя" и "Значение" и работайте с его экземплярами

Comment: а зачем знать имя, если можно обращаться непосредственно по индексу?

Comment: @Grundy Это понятно,но мне ещё нужно присвоить лейбл соответствующему значению. Т.е. if(sort[0]=temp1){ label1.Text = "Текст" }

Comment: @ExzoTikFruiT напиши plz, чем мой вариант не подходит!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант: использовать Dictionary, где ключ - значение переменное, значение - имя переменное, пример для вашего примера:

```
double d1 = 1.1d;
double d2 = 1d;
double d3 = -1.5d;
double d4 = 2d;

Dictionary<double, string> names = new Dictionary<double, string>
{
    [d1] = nameof(d1),
    [d2] = nameof(d2),
    [d3] = nameof(d3),
    [d4] = nameof(d4)
};

double[] sort = new double[] { d1, d2, d3, d4 }.OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();

Console.WriteLine($"First element: {sort[0]}, name: {names[sort[0]]}"); //-1.5 d3
```

Answer (score 1):

Этого сделать нельзя.

Переменная- это фикция нужная нам для удобного чтения кода. После компиляции в IL-коде не хранятся названия переменных(кроме, например, полей класса.).

Answer (score 1):

вот такой трюк:

```
        double[] sort = new double[] { 6, 5, 1, 2, 4, 3 };
        int count = sort.Count();
        int[] index = new int[count];
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                    index[i] = i; //заполняю массив соответствия  

        Array.Sort(sort, index);
        for (int i = 0;i< count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"sort: {sort[i]}; index: {index[i]}");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

[image: скрин вывода консоли]

массив `index` указывает на каком индексе находилось значение
целевой массив сортируется - сохрани его раньше если он нужен

Comment: или можешь использовать `sort[index[i]]` вместо `sort[i]` в своей "необычной" сортировке;     
а перемещать значения массива `index`